# Suprimir clausula WHERE caso seja passado Zero ou Nada CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou trabalhando com o `CakePHP 3.0` e criei uma `query` para seu `ORM`, esta query esta funcionando perfeitamente porém agora necessito que caso um determinado parâmetro seja **0** ou **nada** seja passado para o método a clasula `where` seja suprimida.

**Método que cria a `query` para o `ORM`**

```
public function listProductsByTrend($subCategoryId, $productsQuantity, $column, $order)
    {
        $products = TableRegistry::get('products');
        $query = $products->find();
        $query->select(['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail'])
            ->where(['sub_category_id' => $subCategoryId])
            ->order([$column => $order])
            ->limit($productsQuantity);
        return $query;
    }
```

Se **$subCategoryId** for **0** ou nem sequer algo seja passado a clasula `where` deve ser suprimida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo. Só segmentar a lógica:

```
public function listProductsByTrend($subCategoryId, $productsQuantity, $column, $order)
{
    $products = TableRegistry::get('products');
    $query = $products->find();
    $query = $query->select(['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail']);
    if ($subCategoryId > 0) {
        $query = $query->where(['sub_category_id' => $subCategoryId]);
    }

    return $query->order([$column => $order])->limit($productsQuantity);
}
```